# What does $array2 += $array1 do?

Tags: php, array-merge

I've seen the following often lately and I'm wondering what it does? I can't seem to find it in the PHP manual.

```
 $arr1 = array('key' => 'value1');
 $arr2 = array('key' => 'value2');
 $arr1 += $arr2;
```

Is it similar to an [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge)?

I know what the following does, but I don't understand what it does when working with an array:

```
 $var1 = 1;
 $var2 = 2;
 $var1 += $var2;
 echo $var1; // 3
```

Comment: As the accepted answer holder, I would suggest accepting the top-voted answer instead so I can delete my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **+** operation between two arrays acts like a UNION.

Answer (score 22):

`$arr1 += $arr2` is short for `$arr1 = $arr1 + $arr2`.

The `+` array operator does the following:

- Create a new array that contains all the elements of `$arr1` and `$arr2`, except for the next condition.
- If both operands have elements with the same **key**, only the element of `$arr1` will be present.
- The elements of `$arr2` will be after those of `$arr1`.

This is different from [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge), which:

- Creates a new array that contains all the elements of `$arr1` and `$arr2`, except for the next condition.
- If both operands have elements with the same **string key**, only the element of **`$arr2`** will be present.
- Elements with **numeric keys** will be renumbered from 0, starting with the elements of `$arr1`, and then moving to the elements of `$arr2`.
- The elements of `$arr2` will be after those of `$arr1`, except the string elements, which will be in the position of the first array in which they appear.

Example:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(1 => 'value1.1', 10 => 'value1.2', 's' => 'value1.s');
$arr2 = array(1 => 'value2', 2=> 'value2.2', 's' => 'value2.s');
var_dump(array_merge($arr1,$arr2));
$arr1 += $arr2;
var_dump($arr1);
```

Result (edited for clarity):

```
array(5) {
  [0]   => string(8) "value1.1"
  [1]   => string(8) "value1.2"
  ["s"] => string(8) "value2.s"
  [2]   => string(6) "value2"
  [3]   => string(8) "value2.2"
}
array(4) {
  [1]   => string(8) "value1.1"
  [10]  => string(8) "value1.2"
  ["s"] => string(8) "value1.s"
  [2]   => string(8) "value2.2"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator in PHP when applied to arrays does the job of array **UNION**.

```
$arr += array $arr1;
```

effectively finds the union of `$arr` and `$arr1` and assigns the result to `$arr`.

Answer (score 2):

One of the differences between `array_merge()`, and the sum of two arrays is evident in the following snippets. (See also https://3v4l.org/TcNBF.)

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array(1 => "data");
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

The index in `$result` will be 0.

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array(1 => "data");
$result = $array1 + $array2;
```

The index is not changed; the index is still 1.